# Script is not running at the same time as the loop

Tags: php, javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I currently have a for loop and I am running a script inside it.

I logged whenever the loop ran and whenever the function was executed.

This is a sample of my code:

This script is in a loop that runs 3 times

```
<script>
console.log ("LOOP");
var impressions = [<?= implode(",", $prod_impression_dots) ?>];                             
var testdata = [
{
    "key" : "Impressions" ,
    "type": "line",
    "values" : impressions,
    "yAxis": 1
}    
].map(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
        return series;
    });

nv.addGraph(function() {
     console.log ("Add graph is called here");
     console.log (testdata);
     var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
                .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
                .x(function(d,i) { return i })
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
        if (typeof (dx) == undefined || d > 1000) {
            dx = new Date (d);
        }
        else {
            dx = new Date (dx);
        }
        return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(dx) : '';
        });

chart.yAxis1
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

chart.yAxis2
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.4f'));

d3.select('#chart<?= $counter ?> svg')
.datum(testdata)
.transition().duration(500).call(chart);  
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
});
</script>
```

Below the script is the div tag

```
<div id='chart<?= $counter ?>' style="width:1150px;height:300px;font-size:11px;margin-top:5px">
            <svg> </svg>
            </div>
```

After running this. The output in the console log is as follows;

```
LOOP 
LOOP 
LOOP 
Add graph is called here 
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
Add graph is called here
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
Add graph is called here
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
total 199 nv.d3.js:40
```

I am just wondering why the function isn't executed right after one iteration of the loop. This causes all the graphs to have the same data.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it's called async? search the docs if you can call if synchronously if you need to.

Comment: The documentation for NVD3 is sparse, where else can I look to figure out the source of the issue?

Comment: or google it. I won't search for you ;-) I give suggestions/hints.

Comment: The call to the model uses AJAX, which is asynchronous.

Comment: Instead of using a loop, put everything in a function. Call the function again at the end of the `addGraph` callback function to iterate.

Comment: So apparently the reason was with the div tag.

I put 

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    });
    </script>

around it and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Definitely your addGraph complete function gets called asynchronously. You can work around this like this.

```
<script>
console.log ("LOOP");
var impressions = [<?= implode(",", $prod_impression_dots) ?>];                             
var testdata = [
{
    "key" : "Impressions" ,
    "type": "line",
    "values" : impressions,
    "yAxis": 1
}    
].map(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
        return series;
    });

nv.addGraph((function (testdata) {
     return function() {
     console.log ("Add graph is called here");
     console.log (testdata);
     var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
                .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
                .x(function(d,i) { return i })
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
        if (typeof (dx) == undefined || d > 1000) {
            dx = new Date (d);
        }
        else {
            dx = new Date (dx);
        }
        return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(dx) : '';
        });

chart.yAxis1
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

chart.yAxis2
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.4f'));

d3.select('#chart<?= $counter ?> svg')
.datum(testdata)
.transition().duration(500).call(chart);  
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
}
})(testdata));
</script>
```

Comment: So apparently the reason was with the div tag.

I put 

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    });
    </script>

around it and it solved the issue